# mysqli::insert_id returning wrong id on duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql-insert-id, on-duplicate-key

When using mysqli::insert_id in PHP for INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, I keep getting the next auto increment rather than the updated row if the row is updated. In the same database but in another table, I don't have this behavior when using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Instead, I get the id of the updated row. But now for some reason in a new table I have created, I keep getting the next id that doesn't even exist. Both tables are MyISAM, and have an auto increment field. I don't understand why they behave differently.

Example:

```
==================================
Table: example
==================================
id  |   unique_field    |   data
==================================
1   |   unique1         |   123
2   |   unique2         |   456

INSERT INTO
    example
SET
    unique_field = 'unique1',
    data = '321'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    data = '321'


// mysqli::insert_id returns 3 (not 1)!!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column and INSERT ... UPDATE
>   inserts a row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value. If the statement updates a row instead,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful. However, you can work around this
>   by using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column. To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful for updates, insert rows
>   as follows:
>
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3; The DELAYED option is ignored when you use
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does indeed give the result I was hoping for. But I don't understand why I don't have to do this for the other table I mentioned.

Comment: Could you post both examples and table structures?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot. However, I did some more experimenting and noticed that if I use NOW() somewhere in the UPDATE side of the query, the id will become the same as the updated row. So odd. Basically that's what differing the two tables in terms of functions being called - I use NOW() in one of the insert-update queries and not in the other one.

Comment: That has to be some kind of bug.. Setting a field to NOW() shouldn't affect what id is returned.